# Question over Riemann sums and limits

Tags: integration, limits

I've been working on a problem for about a week that I'm supposed end up with an integral expression. However, I keep coming up against expressions of this form

$\Sigma_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - (\frac{\Delta f(x_i)}{\Delta x_i})^2 \Delta x_i) \Delta x_i$

From here, I can get the form

$\Sigma_{i=1}^n (f(x_i)\Delta x_i - (\Delta f(x_i))^2)$

If I take the following limit

$\lim_{n\to \infty, ||p||\to0} \Sigma_{i=1}^n (f(x_i)\Delta x_i - (\Delta f(x_i))^2)$

I get

$\int f(x)dx - \lim_{n\to \infty, ||p||\to0} \Sigma_{i=1}^n (\Delta f(x_i))^2$

Im not sure how to handle the last term.

I know that if I reorganized it a bit differently I can get any one of the following three expressions

$\int f(x)dx - \lim_{n\to \infty, ||p||\to0} \Sigma_{i=1}^n (\Delta f(x_i))^2$

$\int f(x)dx - \lim_{n\to \infty, ||p||\to0} \Sigma_{i=1}^n f'(x_i^*)\Delta f(x_i) \Delta x_i$

$\int f(x)dx - \lim_{n\to \infty, ||p||\to0} \Sigma_{i=1}^n (f'(x_i^*))^2(\Delta x_i)^2$

But I'm not sure how to handle any of them

Comment: The second term seems to converge to $0$. If you split the mesh 10 times finer, you will have 10 times so many summands but they will be 100 times smaller (because of the square)..

Comment: @PeterFranek what kind of argumentation is that? Are you implicitly assuming that $f$ is Lipschitz-continous with constant $\leq$ 1? And even if you had that, your argument only shows that $\Delta f(x_i) \to 0$, which does not imply the convergence of the series.

Comment: @user159517 It seems to me that my argument works for Lipschitz functions, not just with constant $\leq 1$. And $\Delta f(x_i)\to 0$ follows from only continuity. But on the other hand, I agree that my comment was not very formal.

Answer (score 1):

With the OP's notations, if $f'$ exists and is bounded on $[a,b]$, then the mean value theorem implies
$$
(f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i))^2 \leq \|f'\|_\infty^2 (\Delta x_i)^2 \leq \|f'\|_\infty^2\,\|p\|\,\Delta x_i.
$$

Therefore,
$$
\sum_i (\Delta f(x_i))^2 \leq \|f'\|^2_\infty \,\|p\|\,(b-a)
$$
which tends to $0$ as $\|p\| \to 0$.